# How do you handle HTTP Requests in Dart / Flutter Web Applications?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, authentication, https

I see there is an HTTP Dart Package found at https://pub.dev/packages/http

The documentation & examples provided look acceptable.

Is this an easy way to learn HTTP requests in Dart / Flutter, or should I take a different approach?

My end goal is OpenID Connect & OAuth for QuickBooks Online, so I cannot use Google and other popular OAuth providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official Http package for dart from the dart team.
I say, stay with this package for http requests in Dart/Flutter and if this package doesn't cover your needs later on, there are probably another package that will.

I recommend to use import prefix on this package
so it doesn't conflict with any other package you might use

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

example:

```
final response = await http.post(url, body: ...);
```